# Unreadable Hard Drive Partition

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery

A couple of days ago one of my hard drives stopped being recognised in Windows. It was still recognised in the bios so the actual drive appeared fine and after a bit of investigation I figured that it was the drives partition table that was the problem.

So I downloaded TestDisk and ran it to see if it could do anything. At the time it detected the drive and I could see that the files were still on there so it did indeed look like it was the partition table. I then used TestDisk to recover the faulty partition, which seemed successful.

However it just seems to have made things worse. Now the hard drive is only detectable in the bios and no longer appears anywhere in the system, TestDisk or any partition software.

So what did TestDisk actually do and is there anyway to undo whatever damage it did? Does anyone know of any decent software that can be used to recover lost partitions or should I move onto data recovery tools?

Answer (score 0):

TestDisk is usually really good, but I'd guess your drive is failing for other reasons, whatever caused the first error before TestDisk did anything is probably still there. TestDisk usually only writes partition tables, but doesn't touch the actual data outside partition tables.

If it's in a desktop tower, a cable (or the power, or motherboard) could be going bad, try swapping with other data / power cables (or other known good parts). Or try using the drive in another computer.

Using a live linux USB/DVD/CD you might still be able to read & recover some data from the drive, [ddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) is pretty good with drives that are mostly readable.

Comment: Ahh, not what I was hoping for but probably what's happening. I'll give ddrescue a go and see if that finds anything.

Comment: Actually Testdisk itself can read files (deleted too), and from filesystems that it finds outside of a proper partition (bad mbr/gpt) but I'd be reluctant to try it again if I were you (used a good recent stable version before?). But after getting an image with ddrescue you can then **make a copy of the image** (in case further attempts fail you can "reset") and then try searching for partitions / filesystems and fixing them. And consider multiple backups, including (encrypted) online, just for your personal non-downloadable-again data

Answer (score 0):

The highest probably situation is your hard drive is simply dying slowly.

You need to replace the hard drive.

You could get spinrite from grc.com for $70, and it may or may not recover some of your bad sectors.  You probably have a bad sector in the partition table now, and that is why windows doesn't recognize it.

In terms of get data back if you haven't already backed up all your data it may already be too late.  Spinrite **might** help, but otherwise you will have to pay for professional data recovery specialist which can exceed $1000 depending on the severity of the damage.

If you want to keep using the hard drive **NOPE**. Not ever going to happen, even if spinrite repairs the bad sectors, the drive is dying and continuing to use it is like a time bomb and you never know when it will fail hard and lose all your data.

Comment: Yeah. I've already ordered a new drive and will install it once it arrives. What sucks is that the drive that has failed is was being used as a storage drive, so no back-ups. On the plus side that does mean I should be able to download everything that was on there again, the exception being some old documents and game saves.

Comment: It looks like [[A](https://www.disktuna.com/spinrite-is-not-data-recovery-software/), [B](http://www.myharddrivedied.com/blog/why-spinrite-not-my-data-recovery-software-list), [C](https://serverfault.com/questions/51681/does-spinrite-do-what-it-claims-to-do)] spinrite **is not** a data recovery tool, at best it will attempt to read a bad sector over and over and over again (possibly for a month straight) until it finally works & gets re-allocated, or presumably the failing drive dies. Don't even consider it before rescuing data (ddrescue) or just badblocks to write/reallocate everywhere

Comment: @Xen2050  ddrescue only works if you have a drive large enough to image the whole drive to, which most people don't have.  Even then the hard drive will see the bad sectors and force ddrescue to re-read the sector, probably dozens of times.  I am not saying spinrite is a miracle tool, but ddrescue definitely has frustrations.  I have not even bothered with ddrescue because I never have a drive larger than the failing drive.  It doesn't understand filesystems either so it can waste hours of time reading unused sectors or blocks that the file system knows are already bad.

Comment: You should read ddrescue's documentation, it's practically a definitive tool of data recovery; *"copy data from failing drives causing them as little additional damage as possible... and tries to rescue the good parts first, scheduling reads inside bad (or slow) areas for later. This maximizes the amount of data that can be finally recovered from a failing drive."* If the FS is damaged then it's list of used/bad blocks could be damaged too, but a tool like FSArchiver may be useful to just copy files, if if can find them.

Comment: But if the data's not important enough to get storage for it in the first place, then data recovery's not that important either. In the future using several smaller partitions would aid recovery a lot, to keep actual important data separate, and if one partition goes bad all is not lost & recovery's much easier.

Comment: @Xen2050  Or pay for unlimited cloud backup, for $10/month, and forget about data recovery forever.  Replace the drive, and click restore and let it run in the background until done.

Comment: @Xen2050 Yeah, like I said, this was a storage drive, so essentially this was the back-up drive. The only things of value on there that weren't stored elsewhere were the game saves which I would like to try and save if I can.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same as you and unfortunately sped through testdisk without saving a BACKUP first or even a log file.  My "corrupted" unreadable Windows boot partition is now available to retrieve files from, but now another Windows partition is messed up and the drive is unbootable. .What you can do:

1. Test the hard drive with a bootable CD from the manufacturer website.
2. Get BitDefender Emergency CD which has a great but slow to load interface to view the troublesome hard drive/partition files and folders.
3. If the drive cannot be booted a Windows disc will have Command Prompt to view and "xcopy" file directories (non-system).
4. Check if the Windows install disk recognizes the storage drive or partitions to install Windows onto.

Provide exact details of changes made before or while using testdisk here.  In my case I was changing the size of the  Windows boot partition using installed Acronis Disk Director then not.